# Is there something like SharedDict in Julia?

Tags: dictionary, parallel-processing, julia

I am trying to implement the following for loop in parallel to initialize  a dictionary.

```
heavy=Dict()
for item in list
   heavy[item[1]]=10000000
end
```

Where `list` is a list of lists and each item has three elements.

I was trying something like this:

```
heavy=Dict()
@parallel for item in list
   heavy[item[1]]=10000000
end
```

However it did not work. Reading the [documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/parallel-computing/#scheduling) I found something called SharedArrays that would solve the problem. However it is not clear how to do the same thing but using other data structures like Dict() or Set(). Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work? Using a list of lists with 1, 2, and 3 in the first slots, I got a dictionary mapping 1, 2, and 3 to 10000000.

Comment: I am getting an empty Dict.  Heavy: Dict{Any,Any}()

Comment: You're right, I was running Julia without any worker processes. I'm seeing the same thing now.

Answer (score 5):

The following approach uses a reducing `@parallel` to achieve the same result:

```
list = [[rand(1:3),4,5] for i=1:10000000]; # define random test `list`

@everywhere rdc(d::Vector,i::Vector) = rdc(rdc(Dict(),d),i)
@everywhere rdc(d::Dict,i::Vector) = begin d[i[1]] = 1000; d end
@everywhere rdc(d::Dict,i::Dict) = merge!(d,i)

heavy = @parallel (rdc) for item in list
  item
end
```

`heavy` will now hold:

```
Dict{Any,Any} with 3 entries:
  2 => 1000
  3 => 1000
  1 => 1000
```

The idea is to generate a different dictionary for each worker, populate it and finally combine the dictionaries to one. Hopefully, combining dictionaries is implemented fast enough to make this worthwhile - which seems reasonable.

To implement the idea we define `rdc` and use multiple dispatch to make it serve three purposes: 1) Initialize a new Dict on each worker. 2) Push a new item to an existing Dict on a worker. 3) Combine the Dicts from different workers at the final stage of `@parallel`. The three methods of `rdc` in the code above (in their respective order) implement this.

The need for a SharedDict or SharedArray is avoided, since the workers work on different objects and the final inter-worker communication is hidden in the `@parallel` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like a shared Dictionary exists. While `Dict` is based on a pair of `Array`s, one for the keys and one for the values, it relies on being able to resize them as new items are inserted. Resizing a `SharedArray` in worker processes seems to do weird things, so you can't just swap them out.

If you can get away with growing your memory, you could make a pair of key/value `SharedArray`s with the right length, initialize them in the parallel loop, and then copy the data to your `Dict` in the main processes. That way you can run whatever generates your values in parallel.

Unfortunately, `SharedArray`s will still be problematic if your data is not a bits type. You can use `DArray`s, from the [`DistributedArrays`](https://github.com/JuliaParallel/DistributedArrays.jl) package.

Comment: Another major issue is that, depending on how the values are hashed (some types in Julia are hashed by using their address, which may not be the same in different processes).  It would be very useful to have a shared associate data structure in Julia.